# Разбор по составу слова КОРПОРАТИВ

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор

Заинтересовало, как разбирается слово **корпоратив** по составу. Варианта два:

> корпоратив/
>
> корпор/атив/

С выделением суффикса *-атив-* (иностранного?).

Answer (score 3):

Всё слово - основа, т. е. *корпоратив/*.

Но этимологически "корпоратив", вестимо, однокоренной с "корпорацией" (восходящей к корпусу).

[ЭТИМОЛОГИЯ СЛОВА](http://kak-pravilo.ru/kak_pravilno_pishetsja_slovo_korporativ)

> Слово «корпоратив» произошло от прилагательного «корпоративный», а то
> в свою очередь от существительного «корпорация». «Корпорация»
> образована от латинского «corporatio», что переводится на русский язык
> как «телесность, вещественность». Слово «corporatio» произошло от
> латинского глагола «corporare» - то есть «делать телесным, воплощать»,
> а он от латинского существительного «corpus», что означает «тело,
> плоть».

Не знаю, насколько можно доверять [онлайн-словарю](http://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%9A/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), но последний выуживает корень *корпор/.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А Виноградов предъявляет нам суффиксы *-тив* и -*атив*:

[III. Суффиксы отвлеченных понятий](http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=5310&0a0=3)

> 13. Суффикс -тив(а), -атив(а), выделяемый в заимствованных научно-книжных словах, преимущественно с отвлеченными значениями:
>     прерогатива, инвектива, инициатива и т. п.

Так что случай неоднозначный.

Answer (score 1):

**Корпоратив-Ø.**

Это слово было заимствовано из французского в виде *corporatif* или немецкого в виде *corporativ*, поэтому на синхронном уровне в слове выделяется корень *корпоратив*.

*Использованы данные из "Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений об этимологии слов" РАН*

Answer (score 1):

Вариант разбора: **корпор/аци/я ― корпор/атив/н/ый ― корпор/атив**

**1) Корпоратив ― современное значение слова**

КОРПОРАТИВ, - м. **Разг**. Встреча сотрудников для развлечения и отдыха, организованная с целью укрепления чувства коллективизма, дружелюбия и взаимного доверия в коллективе. Новогодний к.

Происходит от "**корпоративная** вечеринка" — калька англ. **corporate** party.

**2) Родственные слова согласно словарю**

**КОРПОРАЦИЯ**, — [от лат. corporatio - **объединение**] 1. Союз, объединение лиц, организаций, фирм на основе общности профессиональных или сословных интересов  К. юристов. Учёная к. Войти в корпорацию студентов.

**КОРПОРАТИВНЫЙ**,  1. Групповой, замкнутый в пределах одной **корпорации**. К-ые интересы. К-ая жизнь компании. Развивать к-ую культуру общения. 2. Предназначенный для сотрудников данной корпорации. К-ое мероприятие. К. праздник.

**3) История слова "корпоративный"**

Слово "корпоратив" образовалось от слова "**корпоративный**", которое довольно давно применяется в русском языке. Еще в Толковом словаре живого великорусского языка В.И. Даля (1863-1866) указано выражение — "Корпоративные собрания, по званиям, сословиям, состояниям, промыслам", а также "**Корпорация** ж. община, общество, братство, товарищество, сословие, союз людей одного звания, ремесла". [Корпоратив | dslov.ru](http://dslov.ru/koi/i51.htm)